# Display value of model objects django

Tags: python, django, object, view, model

I'm trying to get display the a list of instances of a model in django.

In the simplified case:

```
def sample_order_book(request):
   buybook = TradeOrder.objects.all()
   return HttpResponse(buybook)
```

instead of getting a list of values my response is,

```
TradeOrder objectTradeOrder objectTradeOrder objectTradeOrder objectTradeOrder objectTradeOrder objectTradeOrder objectTradeOrder objectTradeOrder objectTradeOrder objectTradeOrder objectTradeOrder objectTradeOrder objectTradeOrder object
```

When I look at the output in dbshell

```
(test)computer@localhost:~/work/exchange/test/bin$ ./manage.py dbshell
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> SELECT * FROM trade_tradeorder;
```

I get specific values

```
1|somevalue|somevalue|570|652|a
2|somevalue|somevalue|959|289|a
3|somevalue|somevalue|377|866|a
4|somevalue|somevalue|555|369|a
5|somevalue|somevalue|389|144|a
6|somevalue|somevalue|694|576|a
```

I've also tried `filter` and `get` queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your `TradeOrder` model, you'll need to define a `__str__` method:

```
class TradeOrder(models.Model):
   [...]

   def __str__(self):
      return '%s - %s - %s' % (self.trade_amount, self.sell_ticker, self.trade_price)
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/#str

Also instead of returning the queryset as `HttpResponse`, you should make use of django's powerful templating engine.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.list.ListView

Comment: I was using HttpResponse to simplify the question. in the actual code i make use of the templating stuff

Comment: so if i want to it to display multiple values some of which are integers and some strings. how would i do that? the following wont work
`def __int__(self):

  return self.trade_amount

  return self.sell_ticker

  return self.trade_price`

Comment: You should be using `__str__` and not `__init__`. I updated the answer to reflect your model attributes

Comment: hey sorry for the delay accepting your answer, i asked a follow up question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138785/proccessing-django-models