# Processing django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to process a query from my database of model TradeOrder:

```
class TradeOrder(models.Model):
    #denoted in 2 three letter tickers with underscore such as anc_btc
    pair = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #buy_order or sell_order
    order_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #number e.g. .3455 or .190  
    trade_rate = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    trade_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    #name of the account
    trade_order_account = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s'  % (self.pair, self.order_type, self.trade_rate, self.trade_amount, self.trade_order_account)
```

when i execute under views.py for my app

```
buyorders=TradeOrder.objects.filter(pair="anc_btc", order_type="buy_order")
```

i get a list that looks like this:

```
[<TradeOrder: anc_btc buy_order 7987 7897 a>, <TradeOrder: anc_btc buy_order 7897 789 a>, <TradeOrder: anc_btc buy_order 7897 789 a>]
```

so want to process and refine that data, firstly to compare each item to a new order

something like:

```
            if new_order_type=="buy_order":
                #crosscheck against sell orders
                market_sell_orders = TradeOrder.objects.filter(pair="anc_btc", order_type="sell_order", trade_order_account=price)
                #now i need to sort the orders for trade rates above/greater than $new_order_price
                #how do i do this?
```

i now know that this can be accomplished by adding `.order_by('trade_order_price')`
to the end of the query

```
                if potential_sell_orders is not None:
                #trade
                    do=1
                else: 
                    #no sell orders to fill, submit to order book
                    try:
                        tradeordersubmit=TradeOrder(pair=order_pair, order_type=order_type, trade_rate=price, trade_amount=quantity, trade_order_account=request.user.username) 
                        tradeordersubmit.save()
                        order_error=0
                    except:
                        order_error="1"
```

Comment: And what is your actual problem?

Comment: i dont know what to do with 
`[<TradeOrder: anc_btc buy_order 7987 7897 a>, <TradeOrder: anc_btc buy_order 7897 789 a>, <TradeOrder: anc_btc buy_order 7897 789 a>]`
im pretty sure its a list but i dont know how to break it up and work with it

Comment: It's a list of instances of the `TradeOrder` model, one per database row. You can handle them as you might have learned in the Django tutorials.

Comment: @KlausD. when i looked in the manual @ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/instances/ i really only saw basic CRUD database related functions, it it still unclear to me how work with the instances. is there a specific tutorial you can point me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
now i need to sort the orders for trade rates above/greater than $new_order_price
```

You should refine your QuerySet appropriately using QuerySet methods:

```
 market_sell_orders = TradeOrder.objects.filter(pair="anc_btc", order_type="sell_order", trade_order_account=price, trade_rate__gt=<trade_rate>).order_by('-trade_rate')
```

You can find the tutorial for QuerySet [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: this comment was helpful but it is still unclear to me how to work with instances after your QuerySet.  Once i complete the query and its storted, i would want to do something like `for each instance in market_sell_orders, #fill orders
if market_sell_orders.instance_trade_amount<=new_order_trade_amount: 
dosomething=1`

Comment: this answer was ultimatly the most helpful, i ended figuring everything out in the queryset api in the link provided